# 4 variables how many combos of 3 can you make

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility, combinations, integers

If you have 4 variables

```
A, B, C, D
```

How many combos can you make that use 3 of the variable and are unique (order matters), so I mean A,B,C and B,A,C only counts as 1, combo.

I have these are there any others?

```
A,B,C
A,B,D
B,C,D
C,D,A
```

Are these the only possibilities?

Thanks

Comment: You did find all of the combinations.  One way to rephrase this is, how many subsets of size $3$ are there in the set $\{A,B,C,D\}$?  The usual phrase is "combinations of four things taken three at a time".

Comment: @hardmath thanks for that I was struggling how to get what I was thinking across, but am I correct in my answer?

Comment: Yes, note that we get a subset of three by picking one of the four to omit.

Answer (score 2):

The order matters. hence the first choice has 4 then 3 then 2 so you will get $4(3)(2) =24$ Here are some
A,B,C

A,C,B

A,B,D

A,D,B

A,D,C

A,C,D

If the order is not matter you will divide this by $3(2)(1)$ The number of orders of three elements.

Answer (score 1):

For how many combinations, you have it.

C is **combination**. n is the number of items. r is the number of items to be chosen

```
nCr = n!/(r!(n-r)!)
4C3 = 4!/(3!(4-3)!)
    = 24/(6*1)
    = 4
```

**Permutations** is 24. 
P is permutations.  n and r are same as above.

```
nPr = n!/(n-r)!
4P3 = 4!/(4-3)!
    = 24/1
    = 24
```

Another way to think of permutations in this case is you have 4 items to choose from. When you pick one, you now have 3. When you pick the from 3, you now have two. Or

```
4*3*2=24
```

The formula simply takes 4*3*2*1 (4!) divided by the number of spots you didn't fill, which is one.